# How to disable Scroll when Preloader is Active, with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to disable the Scroll while my Preloader is active.
I am using this JQuery, which is overall working fine for my preloader but unable to disable the scroll when the preloader is active.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").addClass("loaded");
    }, 3000);
});
```

I have tried

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

But this disables scroll permanently when the preloader goes off. And Scroll remains enable when preloader is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `overflow: hidden` in your css to the body and add auto when the loaded class is being added you can set it to `auto`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").addClass("loaded");
        $('#loader').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body.loaded {
  overflow: auto;
}

#loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.page {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="loader">
  <span>loading</span>
</div>

<div class="page">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('body').css({ overflow: hidden;height: 100vh; });
```